# ASP.NET Core 3.1 [FromQuery] action properties are null in complex object when using JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-3.1

I've used to work with JQuery AJAX and [FromQuery] in previous .net core versions and it worked fine.
But now it doesn't.
It accesses action, but properties in pagedFilter are null.

Here is my code
Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductsList([FromQuery] PagedFilter<List<ShopFilterItem>> pagedFilter)
{
    var products = productsService.GetPagedFullProducts(pagedFilter.Pager.PageIndex, pagedFilter.Pager.PageSize);
    var result = new ShopProductsList()
    {
        Pager = Pager.ConvertToPager(products),
        Items = mapper.Map<List<ShopItem>>(products)
    };
    return Json(new ApiActionStatusResult<ShopProductsList>(true, result));
}
```

PagedFilter:

```
public class PagedFilter<T>
{
    public Pager Pager { get; set; }
    public T Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Pager:

```
public class Pager
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int ShownRecordsCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }
    public bool HasPrevPage { get; set; }
}
```

ShopFilter:

```
public class ShopFilterItem
{
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    public List<ShopFilterOption> PossibleValues { get; set; } = new List<ShopFilterOption>();
}
```

ShopFilterOption:

```
public class ShopFilterOption
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

JS:

```
var self = this;
const data = {
    Pager: self.Pager,
    Filter: []
};
$.ajax({
    url: self.GetItemsUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    busy: self.Loading,
    data: data
}).done(function (result) {
    if (result.isSuccess) {
        self.Pager = result.data.pager;
        self.Items = result.data.items;
    }
    else {
        alert(result.data.errors[0]);
    }
});
```

Also query which is sent to back-end:

```
https://localhost:44365/ShopAPI/GetProductsList?Pager%5BpageIndex%5D=0&Pager%5BtotalPages%5D=0&Pager%5BpageSize%5D=10&Pager%5BshownRecordsCount%5D=0&Pager%5BtotalRecords%5D=0&Pager%5BhasNextPage%5D=false&Pager%5BhasPrevPage%5D=false
```

And it looks like this on .net side:
[image]

Comment: Could you also add `ShopFilterItem` class?

Comment: @Pieterjan I've updated code, but this class was not used in query anyway